# Flow Enums correctly parsed but not transformed

Tags: babeljs, flowtype

In my React app, I'm trying to migrate from my "old school" JS enums to Flow Enums:
https://flow.org/en/docs/enums/

(I think) I've done everything listed here:
https://flow.org/en/docs/enums/enabling-enums/

eslint and flow check are both happy (zero error) and the enums work as expected when I type code.

But when I start my app, they are not transformed and I get this:

```
ERROR in ./src/types.js
Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\foo\src\types.js: Unexpected token, expected "{" (16:7)

  14 | |};
  15 |
> 16 | export enum FooEnum {
     |        ^
  17 |   On,
  18 |   Off,
  19 |   Default
    at instantiate (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:366:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3453:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.unexpected (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3491:16)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExport (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:16044:16)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExport (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:6170:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementContent (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14893:27)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14777:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5951:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\foo\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15420:25)
```

Package-wise, all of them are in their latest version and I've installed:

- [babel-plugin-transform-flow-enums](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-flow-enums)
- [eslint-plugin-ft-flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-ft-flow)
- [flow-enums-runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-enums-runtime)

My Babel config is:

```
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow",
        {
          "enums": true
        }
      ],
      "babel-plugin-transform-flow-enums"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-flow",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
```

Also, calling Babel from a command line correctly transforms the enum. I'm using this command:

```
npx babel src/types.js
```

What could I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

So, after struggling for hours, I eventually found out that 
[react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) was messing up with my Babel plugins.

I ended up installing [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra), which allowed me to explicitely use my Babel config:

```
const {useBabelRc, override} = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
   useBabelRc()
);
```